# How to insert values in PostgreSQL faster than insert() value() functions?

Tags: perl, postgresql, sap-iq

I have an optimization issue. At the moment I am using DBI in Perl to connect to IQ(Sybase) then load the values into a hash, I then connect to PostgreSQL and use that hash to do a line by line insert with `insert() value()`. This is very slow. Does anyone know of a faster way to run this? My main problem is the two different DB servers and I need to avoid a hash when inserting so some type of bulk insert would be ideal just not sure how?

Answer (score 1):

Populating a PostgreSQL database [is documented here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html). The [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command is your fiend.

- Use COPY
- Remove Indexes
- Remove Foreign Key Constraints
- Increase maintenance_work_mem
- Increase checkpoint_segments
- Disable WAL Archival and Streaming Replication
- Run ANALYZE Afterwards

Comment: That could work but I need 2 connections on DBI and that is where the problem comes in I am uncertain how to use copy with DBI to copy from Sybase to PostgreSQL in Perl